# ¿Cuál es el mecanismo de impacto? ¿Y por qué se dice que el sustantivo tiene incidencia interna?

Tags: lingüística

I have a hard-time understanding what is the "mecanismo de impacto" always appearing in advanced spanish grammar, and also why is it said to have "internal impact" ?
Best Regards.

Comment: Can you provide a link of where you saw that? I cannot find any example...

Comment: https://www.persee.fr/doc/igram_0222-9838_1991_num_50_1_3249#:~:text=La%20th%C3%A9orie%20de%20l'incidence,-Nous%20ne%20pouvons&text=Nous%20rappellerons%20le%20principe%20qui,il%20se%20destine%20un%20support.

Comment: That link is not much help here as you are expecting us to read through pages of dense text to find where it mentions the phrase. To compound the problem you are asking about a phrase in Spanish while the linked article is in French.

Comment: I'm afraid that, unless you provide the context where "mecanismo de impacto" appears as related to advanced Spanish grammar (which sounds really weird), this question will remain unanswered.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no "mecanismo de impacto", at least not one that "always appears" in advanced Spanish grammar. It is probably a loose translation of "mécanisme de l'incidence", which appears to be more or less limited to the so-called "théorie psychoméchanique" of Gustave Guillaume. I did not know that his theories were the dominant ones in French formal grammar. I guess you are a fan?